# recover files from encrypted home folder

Tags: linux, data-recovery, linux-mint, disk-encryption

I can't seem to find the answer to my questions -- hence my posting this here.

1. I have encrypted my home folder in LinuxMint 15 Cinammon x64. If I create images of LM's  partitions via fsarchiver, how do I go about selectively restoring home folders, and files from the FS images?
2. I haven't done this yet; but can I restore another user's home folder into another user; both unencrypted. Is that a fairly common thing to do in Linux/ubuntu? I mean is the process fairly straightforward? What if the home folder I want to copy over to another user is encrypted?